# Best resources for swedish slang

Tags: swedish, slang

My question is just that -- I've been a student of russian language and literature, thee resources for slang and profanity are hugely entertaining and vast on the internet, I've used them to mix in when the lessons get too formal.

I have struggled, though, to find anything like slang resources, recent foreign loanwords, subculture markers, anything of that nature on the swedish language on the internet. Does anybody have an idea, where to start looking for this kind of stuff?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The lack of resources might have cultural reasons; compared with Russian, Swedish slang is more integrated into the official language, and is virtually never offensive as such. If you are interested in a particular region, subculture or historical period you might need to track up that particular one. The only general suggestion would be to look into Romani loanwords, which often have the connotation of having a slang touch to it, however, most modern speakers don't even know they are from Romani, and words as _tjej_, _klämma_ or _nobba_ might not even be regarded as slang.